# How to bring Circle Page Indicator to the front in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, indicator

I have a view pager gallery and a circle page indicator in the bottom of the view. I want to bring page indicator in front of the view pager and make it transparent if it's possible as like in iphone image gallery. Do you have any idea how to do it ?

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Here is the xml code as the solution. Thanks to @sanna

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/gallery_view"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the new appearance of my gallery.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code for imageview??

Comment: @kgandroid Image View is inside the ViewPager. There is nothing special about it, just full screen ImageView.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use RelativeLayout with your Pager covering the whole view first and then add the indicator view with parentAlignBottom=true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works quite well. you can also see my edit as the solution.